# 401 Unauthorized response to login form not being caught by $http or Restangular error catching?

Tags: angularjs

I have the following code for my login form:

```
$http.post('url', {user: {email: $scope.user.email, password:$scope.user.password}}).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log(status);
                console.log(data);
        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                window.alert("invalid");
        });
```

I also did the same in Restangular and had the same issue. Logging in with valid credentials works fine.

My rails backend API is properly returning a 401 Unauthorized response. Any ideas on why when I type in an invalid email/password the error code never runs?

Thanks!

Comment: You are saying that the alert is never called when there is a failed login attempt? If so, is the success handler called?

Comment: For any Googlers coming here (like me): the reason this was occuring for me is I had another interceptor that was not properly rejecting the promise inside its `responseError` method.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out my 401 interceptor was getting in the way. The one from: 
https://github.com/kidovate/angularjsauthseed/blob/master/js/app.js

I added a flag in my request to avoid the 401 authorization check and it now works.

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you did?  I'm running into the same error with Restangular and the auth interceptor.